# Mod Rewrite For All URLs That Contain Certain String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I go about redirecting all instances of a URL that containt -2.html with just .html?

So for instance I would want www.url.com/slug-2.html to redirect to www.url.com/slug.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Redirect :

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^-]+)-2\.html$ http://url.com/$1.html
```

Comment: Thanks Starkeen, but that doesn't redirect for me. Looks like it should but it doesn't. Just brings up the www.url.com/slug-2.html/ URL